# authroize.net ARB subscription with number varying number of months between payments

Tags: authorize.net

I'm an ASP.NET developer and I need to create a subscription service through Authorize.net's ARB API where the number of months between payments varies: subscription type 1 is every 2 months, type 2 is every 3 months and type 3 is every 6 months. I can’t figure out how to create the subscription with varying intervals.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Subscriptions using the ARB API have a consistent interval between payments. Without one you must use the CIM API and create your own payment scheduling engine.